# android - how to create Avd's for different screen sizes with different densities

Tags: android, android-emulator

I implemented the application which supports the multiple screens. I want to test whether this application is supporting or not. For this i need information regarding how to create different AVD's which supports different screens sizes and densities. It means how to create small screen size with ldpi avd,small screen size with hdpi avd,etc. can anybody help me.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create emulator with any size..

see this image.. you can set width & height in Resolution..
[image: image..]

Comment: here size 512 means what? How to set the density?

Comment: I didnt checked density but you could check by modify value of **Abstracted LCD density** which is in image..

Answer (score 0):

go to `window -> andorid SDK and AVD Manager -> New`

in that window you can set properties for your AVD.

Answer (score 0):

Windows->android sdk and avd manager->new  and give ur avd type and screen resolution and on starting that avd u can set the screen size and monitor Dpi

I am using 400x800 for samsung galaxy-s